# filtering for multiple values on one column based on values from another column

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Previously I asked about filtering one column for multiple values where all of them must be present in the column, otherwise no results should be given. I recieved good answer, but this time my request changed somewhat and i need something different.

So I need to filter one column for couple values and show results only if all those values are there AND all those values are related to one value in another column.

Example table:

+----+--------+----------+
| id | Fruit  | Color    |
+----+--------+----------+
| 1  | apple  | green    |
| 2  | apple  | yellow   |
| 3  | banana | green    |
| 4  | banana | yellow   |
| 5  | mango  | green    |
+----+--------+----------+

E.g. if values 'green and yellow' are submitted, only fruits that have both of these colors should be in the result set, in this case 'apple' and 'banana'. All other rows should be dismissed.

I am using MySQL with php.

Example "wrong code":

```
select Fruit FROM table WHERE Color = green AND Color = yellow
```

Must return first 4 rows but not 5.

Thank you
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need each fruit name only once:

```
 SELECT Fruit FROM table WHERE Color IN ('green', 'yellow')
    GROUP BY Fruit HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Altough all three answers gave the same correct result, this one suited me most. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, in that case, you need all (fruit,color) pairs that appear exactly twice.  You can use a count to filter that out, like so:

`select fruit
from(
    select fruit,count(1) as freq
    from table
    where color in (green,yellow)
    group by 1
    )freq_table
where freq=2;`

This, of course, assumes that no (fruit,color) pair appears more than once.  If so, then you might want a third level of subquerying where you select fruit,color from table group by 1,2.

Comment: Well, pedantically it could be more than 2, since it doesn't appear there are constraints on the data (so in theory there could be more than 2 resulting rows, some of which are duplicated).  So I would change `WHERE freq = 2` to `WHERE freq >= 2` (where 2 is the number of values in the `IN` clause)...

Comment: There definitely appears fruit,color pair more than once. Thank you for help, i'm going to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll want to join the table on itself.

```
SELECT a.Fruit 
FROM table AS a
JOIN table AS b ON a.Fruit = b.Fruit
WHERE a.Color = 'green'
    AND b.Color = 'yellow'
```

But, instead, I'd suggest properly [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data, which would make this query much easier (and much more efficient)...

Comment: Actually this "example" table is a "virtual result set" generated by joining other tables so I can't normalize it further (well at least to my knowledge). Thank you for reply, I'll try your code

Comment: It's not clear to me why you believe the sample data is not normalized?

Comment: @Larry: Quite simple.  Color is clearly a duplicated element, so it doesn't qualify as [2nd Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).  (The same could be said for Fruit as well).  I'm not saying it **needs** to be 100% fully normalized, just that it's definitely not 2nd normal or greater...

Comment: It looks normalized to me (but I would drop the ID and use {fruit,color} as key instead).

Comment: color appears to vary independently of either ID or fruit value.